# Fourth row of VP Matrix

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication, glm-math

If have a quesstion regarding matrix multiplication.
What's the information stored in the fourth row of a View Projection Matrix?
I thought rotation and scaling information is stored in the upper 3x3 Matrix, translation then in the fourth column with the last element set to 1.
Im struggling because i get following results for my VP Matrix:

When applying no rotation and no translation (note all values are rounded):

```
0.34 0 0 0
0 0.61 0 0
0 0 -1 -0.2
0 0 -1 0
```

Applying translation by -100:

```
0.34 0 0 0
0 0.61 0 -61.73
0 0 -1 -0.2
0 0 -1 0
```

Translation by -100, then rotate 30° on positive X-Axis, afterwards rotate 180° on positive Y-Axis:

```
-0.34 0 -3 0
0 0.53 0.3 -53.46
0 -0.5 0.86 49.8
0 -0.5 0.8 50
```

It doesnt look right to me. The funny part: It works. So whats the information of this line?

```
0 -0.5 0.8 50
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, your matrix looks a bit odd. Normally, the fourth row would contain the 4th component of the homogeneous coordinate frame, that is, something like `[x,y,z]/w` which would need to add up to 1 across the row for affine transformation. I guess your matrix works because the odd numbers in your fourth row are factored into the upper `3x3` part of the matrix. Did you try to change the order of your matrix concatenation, such as `M'=M1*M0` vs. `M'=M0*M1`. A very good explanation of homogeneous coordinates is given by Jim Blinn in his Dirty Pixels and articles.

[Also, this website contains a good walkthrough regarding homogeneous transforms](http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix/projection-matrices-what-you-need-to-know-first)